# Como hacer la llamada a una clase desde otra ventana python con la arquitectura mvc

Tags: python, mvc, tkinter

Quiero trabajar bajo la arquitectura mvc en python.
Tengo creado 3 carpetas una Modelo, Vista, Controlador, dentra de cada una tengo un **init**, lo que quiero tener una ventana principal en la main.py en la raiz, y dentro de la carpeta vista quiero hacer una ventana secundaria.
Cuando llame de la ventana principal con un boton, me traiga la ventana secundaria que viene en la carpeta vista. Lo he estado intentando pero la verdad soy nuevo en python, sera que alguien me podría ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Añade código o parte de lo que has intentado